# JSONP and object this

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jsonp

I have a Javascript code that uses a function and keys, which I can use with the "this" object, but I added one part JSONP to consume Web services and I can not access the "this" object, forcing to change all the code to put the entire route from window. This is my code original:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    console.log("Hello World!");
    window.programOne = window.programOne || {};

    programOne = {

        varS: {
            var1: "One",
            var2: null,
            var3: "Two"
        },
        demo: function(data){

            console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        },
        execute: function(values){

            // Works correctly when calling from programOne.execute({ "item": "Lorem"});
            //this.demo(values);
            //> { "item": "Lorem"}
            //this.varS.var2 = values;
            //console.log(this.varS.var1);

            console.log(this);
            //It is necessary to use it with the callback. The "this" is undefined object.
            //Does not work here inside "this" object?
            // this.demo(values);
            window.programOne.demo(values);
        },
        start: function(){

            window.executeMyCB = programOne.execute;

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "http://whatever.com/the/script.js&callback=executeMyCB";
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    };
    
    // Demo
    programOne.execute({ "item": "Lorem"});
    
    programOne.start();

}());
```

It is possible to access the functions and variables of the object without having to specify it with "window"? From the own script to get access to, but since the function (`window.executeMyCB`) running JSONP will not let me use `this`. I think that for being a novice in Javascript I do not understand very well and adapt this code solved my error, and understand my question/operation of this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the object to the global function you create:

```
window.executeMyCB = programOne.execute.bind(programOne);
```

---

Or try changing the call to access the method via the object. Not sure if this will work with your service or not:

```
"http://whatever.com/the/script.js&callback=programOne.execute"
```

---

Since you have a jQuery tag, you could also use `$.proxy` instead of `.bind()` if you're supporting legacy browsers.

```
window.executeMyCB = $.proxy(programOne, "execute");
```

Comment: Thank you. It works correctly, I am now reading about bind to understand why it works